# Eclipse RSE: what's the voodoo for connecting to Windows FTP?

Tags: eclipse, ftp

When using RSE in Eclipse to make an FTP connection, I keep getting *"Security Violation - 530 Valid Hostname is Expected."*

Now, when specifying the user-name at the prompt, I *did* use the **hostname|username** syntax that Microsoft FTP requires, which should solve the 530 problem.  But it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

*Well, isn't that bloody weird?*  "Suddenly, it worked."

P.S.:  Yes, you do have to use the "pipe syntax" mentioned in the original post.  I have no idea why it suddenly started working, but I'll take it . . .